# How to disable eslint rule max line length for paragraph in <template> of vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, eslint, airbnb-js-styleguide

I am using airbnb eslint and currently I am getting error:

> error: Line 6 exceeds the maximum line length of 100 (max-len) at
>   path/to/file.vue:6:1:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    .container
      .row
        .col-xl-10.mx-auto
          p Please let us know how you got here, and use the header buttons to navigate back to safe harbor.
</template>
```

Is there a way to disable lint for paragraph text like above?
Also, how to increase the line length from 100 to 120?

Comment: Looks like there's an open issue for this with eslint https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/260. Edit: It's actually a closed issue -- you can use directive comments!

Comment: Also, there is nothing stoping you from wrapping the paragraph so it's more readable

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For `eslint-plugin-vue` >= `4.1.0` you can use directive comments to disable eslint.

https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/commit/ad84e0ba6d81f24583e65fc70b1d9803d73d3ed9

```html
<template>
  <!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/max-attributes-per-line -->
  <div a="1" b="2" c="3" d="4">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work if I use `<template lang="pug">`?

Answer (score 113):

### Update

There has been some updates to eslint-plugin-vue in the past 4 years. The comments in templates can now be used to override eslint settings.

#### For next line only

```html
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line max-len -->
<my-reasonably-long-component>...</my-reasonably-long-component>
```

#### For multi-line purpose

```html
<!-- eslint-disable max-len -->
<my-reasonably-long-component>
  ...
</my-reasonably-long-component>
<!-- eslint-enable max-len -->
```

In addition, as of `eslint-plugin-vue v6.1.0` the `vue/max-len` rule was added, which ads more control about how the length rules

```js
{
    "vue/max-len": ["error", {
        "code": 80,
        "template": 80,
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "comments": 80,
        "ignorePattern": "",
        "ignoreComments": false,
        "ignoreTrailingComments": false,
        "ignoreUrls": false,
        "ignoreStrings": false,
        "ignoreTemplateLiterals": false,
        "ignoreRegExpLiterals": false,
        "ignoreHTMLAttributeValues": false,
        "ignoreHTMLTextContents": false,
    }]
}
```

If you have more than a couple outliers, tweaking the globals for templates-specifically might work better.

---

### Original Answer

AFAIK, there is no way to apply eslint rules to the template, and specifically to one line in a template. I hope to be proven wrong though.

anyway, because I have a file with lots of text, to get around it, I've added this rule `'max-len': ["error", { "code": 120 }],` in my `.eslintrc.js` file.

here is the structure (with other settings removed)

```
module.exports {
  rules: {
    'max-len': ["error", { "code": 120 }]
  }
}
```

Comment: The same solution works also for npm package.json, esLintConfig section.

Comment: There is a way to disable rules for a set of lines with html comments as demonstrated in another answer

Comment: @Tofandel yes, that wasn't the case at the time of writing,. I've updated the answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: For whole file you can use like
`/* eslint-disable max-len */`

Answer (score 37):

This will disable the rule for the entire template tag. [Official ES Lint docs on disabling rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments)

```
<template>
  <!-- eslint-disable max-len -->
  ...
```

EDIT: If you want to instead disable line length rule for all .vue files, then add this to `.eslintrc.js` (this will also disable the rule for `<script>` and `<style>` tags):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.vue"],
      rules: {
        ...
        'max-len': 'off' // disables line length check
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: You can follow with `<!-- eslint-enable max-len -->` to re-enable the rule after the offending line

Answer (score 12):

You can disable max-len and use [vue/max-len](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/max-len.html) with something like `"template": 9000`. An example:

```
"overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.vue"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "max-len": "off",
        "vue/max-len": [
          "error",
          {
            "code": 120,
            "template": 9000,
            "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true,
            "ignoreUrls": true,
            "ignoreStrings": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

This way you disable the rule only for the `<template></template>` part of a component.

Answer (score 10):

the correct eslint config is this:

```
rules: {
  'prettier/prettier': ['error', { printWidth: 120 }],
},
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add this to your ESLint rules:

```
rules: {
  "vue/max-attributes-per-line": "off"
}
```

This worked for me (even if I rather set it on for my projects).
You can find more information [here](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/max-attributes-per-line.md) if you want.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Vue3, the structure has been changed, `.eslintrc.js` is being merged into `package.json` so that  methods mentioned before is not work for me.

First.

This is the way it works to me
Commented the line in `.editorconfig`

```
[*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
# max_line_length = 100
```

Seconds.

Add the line in `eslintConfig` object in `package.json`

```
"rules": {
  "max-len": ["error", 120]
},
```

Answer (score 3):

what was missing for me is the location of configuration file. in my angular project it is .eslintrc.js

and the part of the configuration code looks like this:

```
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "max-len": ["error", {"code": 120}],
  },
```