# How to set max-len for one file (exception) to 120?

Tags: eslint

With eslint I've my max line length on 80 and I like this besides for one file where I'd like to organize my exports ASC and the only way to do this with my VS Code plugin is that I have each export on one line.

Default my max line length is 80, how can I make an exception for this one file? Is there an eslint comment for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a comment: Put `/* eslint-disable max-len */` at the top of your file (src: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#disabling-rules).

Alternatively, define *overrides* for some rules for specific file patterns in your `.eslintrc` file:

```
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["path/to/your/very/long/*/files.js"],
    "rules": {
      "max-len": ["off"]
    }
  }
]
```

(src: [Turning off eslint rule for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file/65069069#65069069))

I would have marked this question as an exact dupe of [Turning off eslint rule for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file), but bountied questions cannot be marked as dupe.

Related: [How to disable eslint rule max line length for paragraph in <template> of vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468673/how-to-disable-eslint-rule-max-line-length-for-paragraph-in-template-of-vue-js)

Comment: With the comment it's not working for some reason, I'll try the override later today